# Is there a way to preserve file deletion during a merge between branches that don't share a common ancestor?

Tags: git, git-merge

I would like to be able to merge changes that occur in several long lived branches, that all began as orphan branches (say some `orphan-k`-ish branches), into another branch, the `central-orphan`, and have those merges include affecting the deletion of a file that was previously added but was deleted during one of the commits to an `orphan-k` branch, so that it is also deleted in the `central-orphan` branch being merged to.

I'm aware this should be default behaviour, at least, for branches with shared history. I assumed it would be default behaviour for branches with unrelated histories too, but recently found files that would have been removed from the branch being merged to, if that were the case. That is to say, some commit on some `orphan-k` branch deleted a file that had previously existed in it, but the subsequent merge from that `orphan-k` branch didn't remove that file from the `central-orphan`; the diff exclusively included the new files and changes to existing files that hadn't been deleted, but did not include the few files that had been deleted.

I have several branches that all initially started as orphans; i.e. for k in [1, 2, ...]

```bash
git checkout --orphan orphan-k
rm .git/index ; git clean -fdx
git commit -m "Initial empty orphan" --allow-empty
git push --set-upstream origin orphan-k
```

To add each successive relevant commit to each of these orphan branches (with multiple commits being applied over time to the same branches), I follow a procedure to automate committing the relevant built directory contents in a github workflow;

```bash
git config --local user.email "actions@github.com"
git config --local user.name "Github Actions"
export SHORTSHA=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
git fetch origin orphan-k:orphan-k
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/orphan-k
cd .. && mv folder-k/path/in/repo/to/built/dir ../MERGE_TARGET
git rm -rf . && git clean -fxd && git reset
shopt -s dotglob && mkdir folder-k && mv ../MERGE_TARGET/* folder-k/
git add .
git commit -m "Build based on $SHORTSHA" --allow-empty
git push --set-upstream origin orphan-k
```

The above correctly works to commit only what was built in the most recent build process, for a build process that is relevant to the "`k`'th" orphan. If files that used to be in the resulting build no longer are, they are correctly removed from the `orphan-k`-ish branches.

So the issue must be with the next step, but I'm not sure what can be changed about it to include the files being removed from the `orphan-k`-ish branches into the `central-orphan` branch, or if it's possible. The next step runs after the above step for each of the `orphan-k`-ish branches (where `${{ inputs.merge_from }}` would be `orphan-k`);

```bash
git config --local user.email "actions@github.com"
git config --local user.name "Github Actions"
git fetch --unshallow
export FROM_SHA=$(git rev-parse --short=8 origin/${{ inputs.merge_from }})
export TO_SHA=$(git rev-parse --short=8 origin/central-orphan)
git checkout central-orphan && git pull
git merge --squash origin/${{ inputs.merge_from }} --allow-unrelated-histories -X theirs
git commit -m "Auto-merge ${{ inputs.merge_from }}@($FROM_SHA) to central-orphan@($TO_SHA)" --allow-empty
git push
```

The option `--allow-unrelated-histories` is necesary because they don't share any common history, but I assumed that `-X theirs`, which does correctly pick my `${{ inputs.merge_from }}` branch's changes, would also include the files being removed.

But files that were correctly removed from the `orphan-k`-ish branches still exist in the `central-orphan`, and appear to not have been removed, during the merges that ran after the commit that removed them from the `orphan-k`-ish branches.